# chef plugin cloudify error while uploading blueprint

Tags: chef-infra, cloudify

I got an error while I was trying to validate and upload a blueprint I created using chef-plugin for Cloudify. I am importing chef-plugin.

And the error looks like:

```
CloudifyCliError: Failed to validate blueprint my_blueprint.yaml: Missing definition for relationship cloudify.relationships.connected_to which is declared as derived by relationship cloudify.chef.connected_to
```

This is how my blueprint.yaml looks like:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_0

imports:
  - http://getcloudify.org/spec/chef-plugin/1.1/plugin.yaml

node_templates:

  testserver:
    type: cloudify.chef.nodes.WebServer
    properties:
      chef_config:
        version: 11.18.0
        chef_server_url: URL
        validation_client_name: chef-validator
        validation_key: ""
        node_name_prefix: chef-node-
        node_name_suffix: testserver.com
        environment: _default
        runlist: recipe[cookbook::recipe]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please consider properly formatting this question so that the blueprint definition is properly displayed as YAML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an import of `types.yaml`

something along the lines of

```
imports:
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/3.1/types.yaml
```

Be sure to check out the Chef plugin documentation at http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/plugin-chef.html

If this is your first attempt at using Cloudify, I would suggest starting here http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/quickstart.html and only after you've got the basics covered, proceed with the chef plugin.

Comment: Thanks I worked on rewriting my blueprint and it worked fine.